# Show that $\mathcal{F}$ is a normal family on $\mathbb {D}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a family of holomorphic functions on $\mathbb{D}$ so that for any $f\in\mathcal{F}$, $$|f'(z)|\left(1-|z|^2\right)+|f(0)|\leq 1,$$ for all $z\in\mathbb{D}$. Prove that $\mathcal{F}$ is a normal family on $\mathbb{D}$.

Attempt:
Let $0<R<1$ and consider the open disk centered at $0$ of radius $1-R$, $D_{1-R}(0)$. For $z\in \overline{D_{1-R}(0)}$ we have by assumption $$|f'(z)|\left(1-|z|^2\right)+|f(0)|\leq 1$$ $$\implies |f'(z)|\leq\frac{1-|f(0)|}{1-|z|^2}.$$

Thus $$|f(z)|=\left|\int f'(z)\ dz\right|\leq \int|f'(z)|\ dz\leq \int \frac{1-|f(0)|}{1-|z|^2}\ dz.$$

My question is how to bound the last integral to conclude that $\mathcal{F}$ is uniformly bounded on compact subsets of $\mathbb{D}$

Comment: Where are you integrating . $f(z)=\int f'(z)dz$ is not  correct.

Comment: You're right. We are integrating over the entire closed disk, not just the boundary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $K=\{z:|z| \leq 1-r\}$, $0<r<1$. Then  $|f'(z)|$ is bounded on $K$ by $\frac  1{1-r^{2}}$. We can write $f(z)=f(0)+\int_{\gamma} f'(\zeta) d\zeta$ where $\gamma$ is the line segment from $0$ to $z$. It follows from this that $|f(z)|$ is bounded by  $\frac {2-r^{2}} {1-r^{2}}$ on $K$. Since  any compact subset of $D$ is contained in $K=\{z:|z| \leq 1-r\}$ for some $r <1$ we have proved that the given family is uniformly bounded on compact sets. Hence it is a normal family by Montel's Theorem.

Comment: I estimated that $|f(z)|\leq 1+\frac{1}{2}\ln\left|\frac{1+|z|}{1-|z|}\right|$. This should achieve a maximum on $K$. How did you find that particular bound? @KaviRamaMurthy?

Comment: @Sham $|\int_{\gamma} f'(\zeta) d\zeta| \leq \frac  1 {1-r^{r}} L$ where $L$ is the length of the path $\gamma$. The length of the line segment from $0$ to $z$ is $|z|$ which is bounded by $1$. Hence we get the bound $1+\frac  1 {1-r^{r}}=\frac  {2-r^{2}} {1-r^{r}}$.